# Free dll for Asymmetric encryption in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me out to finding any free dll for asymmetric encryption for larger (non plain text like zip files, pdf's etc.) data. Currently availble classes in C# .NET are for asymetric encryption, is limited to plain text ( not more than 100 bytes) data only.
My need is to encrypt/decrypt larger zip(of pdf fies) data in Asymmetric method.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are simply wrong about the encryption classes in. net, as Eric J. notes in his answer.

Comment: Only 100 bytes was encrypted properly due to difference in chipher mode used in open-source implementation and microsoft implementation of AES. It is related to block size, IV, and chipher mode. That information not actual any more. It's all alike the all rumors about weak implementation on .NET cryptography than in java, for example. You can use RSA, SHA, and other asymmetric algorighms freely, without any doubghts or concerns.

Comment: -1 Bad question, wrong guess, anyway. How can i help you, if you not realizing what are you asking for? If you ask how to compress & encrypt, say, 25 GB of data, that will be more spectfic question.

Answer (score 3):

The point is, that - generally speaking - you don't use public/private key encryption for large data, due to its slower performance (compared to symmetric methods).

In general, you use an asymmetric cipher to encrypt a symmetric key, that in turn you then use to encrypt/decrypt your actual data.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5d60997b-ce2a-4cec-8ab4-9d0b45e679f8) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) ("How it works").

Answer (score 2):

The asymmetric encryption built-in to .NET supports large binary files.  Review

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

Can you share why you think only short texts are supported?

Comment: Only 100 bytes was encrypted properly due to difference in chipher mode used in open-source implementation and microsoft implementation of AES. It is related to block size, IV, and chipher mode. That information not actual any more. It's all alike the all rumors about weak implementation on .NET cryptography than in java, for example.

Comment: Guys, you'll be surprised, but what OP saying is true. You really can't do ONLY asymmetric encryption with big files with .NET standard library. Try it yourself, and you'll see. Try encrypting say array of 100000 bytes. The reason why this is implemented this way is because asymmetric algorithms are very slow so it simply inefficient to use them for large blocks of data. So what you are supposed to do instead is using symmetric algorithm on your data first, and then encrypt *the key* asymmetrically. This works very well and this is how it's intended to be used.

Comment: @Artur: AES is symmetric encryption.

Comment: @zespri: I agree that it is slow and not how asymmetric encryption is meant to be used (Christian's answer is good), but I'm not aware that there is a specific byte limitation.

Comment: You are not aware that asymmetric encryption is only designed for encrypting data smaller than it's key size?